# Can't get rid of Onedrive for Business to use Onedrive personal

Tags: windows, onedrive

I installed Office 365 on my Windows 10 machine (office apps work fine). Somehow it also added OneDrive for Business which I have no desire or reason to use. But now I can't get rid of it, and my regular OneDrive personal client doesn't work.

[image]

In the add/remove programs applet I only see "Microsoft OneDrive" (no indication for Business). Since I see no other place to find a client to uninstall, I uninstall it, and redownload the regular personal client. I reinstall it but upon searching for the app to launch it I only still see OneDrive for business. I can't seem to get rid of it!

The only icon in the system tray is the blue (not black and white) OneDrive for Business one. When I right mouse click on it, the tiny menu that pops up only allows me to sync a new library (to my employer) -- but that's not what I want at all.

[image]

I'm willing to have both installed and have the Business one lie dormant, too.

What should I try now?

Comment: Just add your personal account and you should be good...?

Comment: How? I don't see anywhere to enter my credentials

Comment: Settings → Account → Add an account

Comment: OneDrive is built into Windows 10.  So what exactly did you redownload and install?  Sounds like you redownloaded the business client.  The built-in client can handle both by the way.

Comment: True @ramhound, it is built into Windows 10, but you can still download and install the client, which you can find by googling "onedrive client download". My last ditch attempt to get OneDrive personal working for me.

Comment: @Daniel B I do see my Microsoft account, which by the way I use to log in to my machine, listed under "email and app accounts". But no way to do anything with OneDrive, which on my other Windows 10 machines works perfectly normally (letting me pick which folders to sync, which location to choose to sync to, etc.)

Comment: I'm referring to the OneDrive settings dialog. Sounds like looked at the Windows 10 settings app.

Comment: Thing is I can't find the OneDrive settings dialog. I search for "OneDrive" and the only thing that comes up is the OneDrive for Business applet which is totally different looking and has no options I need (just to adjust my employer's OneDrive setup which I don't want or need).

Comment: You have been able to use the built-in client to connect to OneDrive for Business accounts (Sharepoint) and the consumer OneDrive service for awhile

Comment: What's your current OneDrive client used on Windows 10? The **new sync OneDrive desktop client** can sync both personal account and work account. You can search OneDrive in Windows, right-click it and select **Open file location**. In File Explorer, right-click the OneDrive app and select **Properties** > **Shortcur**, check the text in **Target**, if the text ends in **OneDrive.exe**, you have the OneDrive sync client.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Windows 10 and Office 2016 to the latest version to ensure you are using the new OneDrive Sync client.

If you are using the new OneDrive Sync client, start it, right-click the OneDrive icon in the right bottom corner of the taskbar, select **Settings**.

[image]

Under **Account** tab, click **Add an account** to add your personal account.
[image]

Comment: I don't see the black-and-white OneDrive icon in the tray; only the blue OneDrive for Business one, and its context menu looks nothing like this. See the screenshot I added to my post.

Comment: The pixelated icon is actually a SharePoint sync folder. It’s neither OneDrive for Business (although labeled as such) nor OneDrive.

Comment: @chicagonyc You can check the comments I added in your original posting to check what your current OneDrive app version is. In your screenshot, it seems you are not using new OneDrive sync folder.

Comment: You can download the new OneDrive sync client from following link: [Download the latest version of the new OneDrive sync client that's fully released to production](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=844652)